# Finding the click event of DGV button column and transferring to another form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, click, buttonclick

I have a datagrid view with four columns:

```
productid 
productname
productprice
buy (this is button column )
```

Is it possible to find the click event of button column? I mean, if I click on the row 1 button, the corresponding row values will be transferred to another form.

If I click on the row 2 button, the corresponding values are transferred to another form. I am doing WinForms applications. Any ideas or sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: would any one pls help on this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered on the MSDN page for the [DataGridViewButtonColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.aspx).

You need to handle either the CellClick or CellContentClick events of the DataGridView.

To attach the handler:

```
dataGridView1.CellClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellClick);
```

And the code in the method that handles the evend

```
void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Check that the button column was clicked
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "MyButtonColumn")
    {
        // Here you call your method that deals with the row values
        // you can use e.RowIndex to find the row

        // I also use the row's databounditem property to get the bound
        // object from the DataGridView's datasource - this only works with
        // a datasource for the control but 99% of the time you should use 
        // a datasource with this control
        object item = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;

        // I'm also just leaving item as type object but since you control the form
        // you can usually safely cast to a specific object here.
        YourMethod(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have alredy implemented another function for cell click event handler is there any alternative to this.....would you pls suggest

Comment: how can i get the all values in particular row

Comment: @user852714 you can implement as many pieces of functionality as you want in that event handler, particularly as each one will usually only act on the cells of a particular row. For getting the values in a particular row the best way is the method I suggest of using that databound item. Otherwise you can just iterate over the row cells are retrieve each cell value.

Answer (score 0):

using validate cell you can get the (column & row of the cell). Initialize the button as win forms button object, also add a handler that call the click event of the same.